# android list targets command returns an error

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to learn cocos2d-x and obviously I need to first set it up.

I folowed this tutorial http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android and reached to a part where I should go to cmd, move to build dir and type

```
android list targets
```

but when I do that I get an error that "android command is not recognized" or something like that.

What to do people? Also why I do that? I believe that I getting id of android device or whatever with this command?

Thanks

Comment: `android.bat` is in the `<android-sdk>\tools` directory. Either run it from there or add the directory to the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You might have input the wrong paths when setting up your cocos2d-x environment with the `setup.py` script.

I assume you have installed the android sdk and eclipse following the instructions of the [tutorial](http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_run_cpp-tests_on_Android) in the "Download JDK, SDK and NDK" chapter.

Here is how you can fix this:
In the terminal, open `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`

```
$ open ~/.profile
```

In this file you should see a reference to your Android SDK directory:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/<userName>/Dev/AndroidDev/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/
```

Make sure this path is right. If you have nothing like this, re-run the setup.py script in Cocos2d-x root directory.

Restart the Terminal.
The `android` command should work.